# How to parse Latex into Python expression

Tags: python, database, sympy, equation

I found manu libraries like `Sympy` python library, that also in testing but not working properly to parse.

If i have a variable `ABC` want to multiple with `3` but `Sympy` represent `ABC` as `A * B * C`

So any idea about which technique is use for save equation or formula in database and calculate on run time with provides variable value dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

Parsing expressions in Python can be done using `sympy`. For example, `sympy` allows to convert '-5abc^2' into `expression=-5*a*b*c**2` in a following way:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr, standard_transformations, implicit_multiplication_application, convert_xor
transformations = (standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application, ))
expression = parse_expr('-5abc^2', transformations=transformations)
```

You might like to reverse the process (convert expression to LaTeX script) then just call `sympy.latex(expression)`

You can find more info in the [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html) of parsing sympy expressions.

**UPDATE:**
Suppose 'abc' is a single variable. Then '-5abc^2' means -5 squares of abc. This requires definition of custom list of variables that can be split while using `split_symbols_custom(...)` transformation. (I have also replaced `implicit_multiplication_application` with `implicit_multiplication`)

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr, standard_transformations, implicit_multiplication, split_symbols_custom, _token_splittable, convert_xor

def can_split(symbol):
    if symbol not in ('abc',):
        return _token_splittable(symbol)
    return False

transformation = split_symbols_custom(can_split)
transformations = (standard_transformations + (transformation, implicit_multiplication, convert_xor))
expression = parse_expr('-5abc^2', transformations=transformations)
print(expression)
```

So `'-5abc^2'` is parsed as `'-5*abc**2'` now. This can be found in the [documentation of split_symbols_custom](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html#sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.split_symbols_custom)

Comment: But in my case, ABC is a variable that have value 5

ABC. = 5

ABC is single variable not separate character variables

Comment: After some efforts I've got your requirement clarified. Look at my updated answer. Actually, you need to include one more transformation in a parsing mechanism and it's called `split_symbols_custom` over your custom list.

Comment: Despite my notices I've found some bugs here on my update. I'll try to play a little bit more with these transforms to get it fixed.

Comment: The main problem is that adding `transformation` parameter to list (as well as removing it) has no effect which is contradictory to documentation :(